# Any way for Smart UV Project to give more UV real estate to specific faces?

Tags: uv

Smart UV Project produces results where each face takes up a proportionate amount of space in the UV map to its space in the full model. There are times when certain parts of the model could use more detail than others, though I'd rather keep them all as a single material. I can control seams in Smart UV Project, but I was wondering if there was any way to allow specific faces to be weighted to take up more room in the UV map than they normally do when using Smart UV Project?